# What is the Simplest Authentication Method for In-Person eSignature?

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf, authentication, electronic-signature

I am in the process of developing a very basic esignature plugin for WordPress. I am aware of WP Signature, but it doesn't satisfy the requirements for in-person signatures using a tablet. Staff Members will be carrying a tablet, the staff member will type in the Customer's name, fill in the fields if needed, and then show them the original PDF contract. They will then sign within the signature pad, and the signed document will be stored on the server under the Customer's custom post and another copy to the Customer's email address.

Under my state's electronic signature's law (http://codes.ohio.gov/orc/1306), Section **1306.08 (A)** states:

> An electronic record or electronic signature is attributable to a person if it was the act of the person. The act of the person may be shown in any manner, including a showing of the efficacy of any security procedure applied to determine the person to which the electronic record or electronic signature is attributable

So does my current defined process above satisfy that section? I can't use an IP address because it's coming from my staff member's tablet.

Comment: I don't know that SO is the best (or preferred) avenue for soliciting advice. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask That said – here's the top google result for `how to capture e signature wordpress` https://www.approveme.com/

Comment: Changed the post for a more specific question. Sorry about that. I might need to move this.